# Poll extension gves error while inserting in yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am using yii poll extension. I copied the sql file into my db. It works fine untill i vote. But when i click on vote it shows command error.
ie:-
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`poll_vote`, CONSTRAINT `vote_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `poll_vote` (`user_id`, `ip_address`, `timestamp`, `choice_id`, `poll_id`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4);

I havent implemented this part of document.
 1. Setup a User active record with an integer ID returned by Yii::app()->user->id.*

Can anyone help wt does that mean.

I do have users table with uid column in same database. some how im not able to get the point.  And how can i avoid the constraint failure. Im sorry im new to yii..
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's failing since, as you said, you skipped the "Setup a User active record with an integer ID returned by Yii::app()->user->id.*"

The "integrity constraint violation" is stating that the foreign key constraint fails, and goes on to say that the foreign key is the user_id, which you have stated you never created.

Looks like the extension is keeping track of who voted using the user_id, and since you haven't created IDs, you get the error.

For information on how to modify Y ii:app()->user, see [this page](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/6/how-to-add-more-information-to-yii-app-user/)

Comment: hi.. Thanks for the reply.  i hv implemented the id accordingly as  mentioned in the link you have given. but how the error is same. Sorry if i an asking silly question.. but My doubt here is how do i "Setup a User active record with an integer ID returned by Yii::app()->user->id.*"       Is it like 1.create a user table with id column and assign it with Yii::app()->user->id.